# Windows save, open... icons as vector graphics?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, icons, toolbar

For my application (WPF) I'd like to use the standard icons for save, open... However, I'm not aware of them being available as vector graphics? So, where can one get them, is it maybe possible to extract them from some DLL files or whatever? Thank you very much!

Comment: Similar Question having a lot of free sources for vector graphics - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315819/source-for-xaml-toolbar-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons that are included with Visual Studio 2008 are bitmap only, I haven't installed Visual Studio 2010 yet.

There's a package of nice free common toolbar icons in XAML format at: http://www.grafile.com/presentation/Vista_Toolbar_library.html (haven't used them myself yet).

You can find a lot of (usually not free) icons sets by googling "xaml icons", you can find even more if you google "vector icons" but those will usually won't be XAML

Answer (score 0):

Consider using big size icons (eg. 256x256 or 128x128 pix) and wpf would scale them down nicely. Probably you wouldn't make your icons bigger than 128x128 px anyway.

Icons you can use:

- [Crystal Project](http://www.everaldo.com/crystal/?action=preview)

Comment: thanks for your reply, probably using bigger icons is a idea. however I'd like to use the default windows icons, because every windows user knows them. wondering if this is somehow possible?

Comment: First, scaled down version of large icons will not look as good as a version optimized for the correct size and all that scaling will cost you some performance. Second, that icon set is licensed under the GPL, you can only use it in open source projects that are themselves licensed under the GPL.

Comment: @Nir: The Crystal Project are released under LGPL, not GPL. This is a significant difference

Comment: @twk sorry, my mistake, I took a quick look at the license page and missed the L